# Check if String is of Certain Format

Tags: php

I have a form where users can enter a license plate number. After submitting the form i want to check if the license plate given by the users is of a certain format for example, i want to only allow them to submit if the format is any of the below 4:

```
example license plate "1SAM123" (1 number, 3 letters, 3 numbers) 
example license plate "82739F1" (5 numbers, 1 letter, 1 number) 
example license plate "8U89238" (1 number, 1 letter, 5 numbers) 
example license plate "445112" (six digit numbers only)
```

I have tried using substr to get each character of the string and then check each one

```
$plate1 = substr($plate, 0, 1);
$plate2 = substr($plate, 1, 1);
$plate3 = substr($plate, 2, 1);
$plate4 = substr($plate, 3, 1);
$plate5 = substr($plate, 4, 1);
$plate6 = substr($plate, 5, 1);
$plate7 = substr($plate, 6, 1);
```

However i can't seem to check if any of these are integers as substr is making them act like a string, if there is a better way of doing this i will appreciate it thank you

Comment: you should have a look at regex with http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

checkPlate('1SAM123');
checkPlate('82739F1');
checkPlate('8U89238');
checkPlate('445112');
checkPlate('01234FF');
checkPlate('44511200');


function checkPlate($plate) {
    echo $plate . " is " . (isValidPlate($plate) ? "valid\n" : "invalid\n");
}

function isValidPlate($plate) {
    foreach(array(array(1, 3, 3),
             array(5, 1, 1),
             array(1, 1, 5),
             array(6, 0, 0)) as $i) {
        $matches = array();
        preg_match("/[0-9]{{$i[0]}}[A-Z]{{$i[1]}}[0-9]{{$i[2]}}+/", $plate, $matches);
        if (isset($matches) && $matches[0] == $plate)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/c6c9867719fb3b):

```
1SAM123 is valid
82739F1 is valid
8U89238 is valid
445112 is valid
01234FF is invalid
44511200 is invalid
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '[' here: foreach([[1, 3, 3],

Comment: Copy the code again, I just changed `[]` to `array()`.

Comment: Works but if i add more characters to the string it also says it is valid, "1SAM123blaa" for example

Comment: Sorry I rushed a little, try it now. It should work fine. (I also quickly changed [] to array())

Comment: @DaveChen Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but I wouldn't count on the OP for a green ticky if I were you. Have a look at their question history. I'll upvote though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression. PHP uses [PCRE](http://php.net/pcre) (Perl Compatible Regular Expression). An example is provided below that matches what you're looking for...

```
$strings = [
    "1SAM123",
    "82739F1",
    "8U89238",
    "445112",
    "This will not match...",
];

foreach($strings as $string) {
    if (preg_match("#(\d[a-z]{3}\d{3})|(\d{5}[a-z]\d)|(\d[a-z]\d{5})|(\d{6})#i", $string)) {
        echo "The string '$string' matches our expression!";
    }
}
```

Comment: This works however if i add more to the string it still says its valid, example  "1SAM123" will echo out that it matches but "1SAM123blaaa" will also say it matches

Comment: Sure, because it's a match. "1SAM123" matches the expression. It only captures the match and ignores the "blaaa". All explained in [the documentation](http://www.php.net/preg-match) (_check `preg_match`'s third argument_). If you want the string to be an exact match, enclose the expression in a caret and sigil  e.g. (`^only match this expression exactly$``).

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression for this with [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Simply something like this :

```
$pattern = "/[0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{5}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{5}|[0-9]{6}/";
if (preg_match($pattern, $plate_number) === false) {
    // Not valid
} else {
    // Valid
}
```

But this one is an example and a long one, so you need to come up with a better regular expression to validate your data.